# “because of” vs. “on account of”

Tags: meaning, word-choice, conjunctions

Can I always replace “because of” with “on account of”? As in

> I could not enjoy the day **because of** the awful weather.
>
> I could not enjoy the day **on account of** the awful weather.

If these two expressions are same, is there any situation where I should prefer one over the other?

Comment: There are subtle differences. I found a quote on the net that "He did not die on account of a broken heart, he died of a broken heart on account of his lover's infidelity"

Comment: Yes, Kelly Clarkson wisely opted for 'Because of you'.

Comment: Not always. *... the wizard of Oz is one on account, on account, on account, on account, on account, on account, on account of the wonderful things he does.*

Comment: Giggle :) But for those who may not get it, Peter Shor is citing the lyrics of ["We're Off to See the Wizard"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mm3ypbAbLJ8)

Comment: "On account of" makes me think of the Junie B. Jones children's books - and then run to use "because of" instead...

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, *because of* and *on account of* are synonymous.

*On account of* is slightly less appropriate than *because of* in cases that do not involve thought or record.

> The water boiled **because of** the heat.
>
> The water boiled **on account of** the heat.

Both uses are valid, but in this example, *because of* is slightly better than *on account of* because it does not imply thought on the part of the water.

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore, as is often the subtle case with languages, it is difficult for a foreign speaker to "feel" the slightly humorous/awkwardness of "on account of" versus the straightforward "because of" which more clearly designates causality and frankly, as such, sounds more professional in a formal context. I was trying to think of (or manufacture) --an example when I immediately came across another post which referred to one:  J.D. Salinger's *Catcher in the Rye*:

> He'd written me this note asking me … to stop by and say good-by
>   before vacation started, on account of I wasn't coming back.

Notwithstanding the temporal grammatical problem, the phrase conveys a weaker statement of intent than -because" and is a much better portrait of a younger and/or less educated way of speaking. (Journalists for *The Australian* please take note and apply Salinger's language insights in reverse.)

Answer (score 0):

*Because of* & *On account of* can often be used interchangeably - take the following as an example:

*My car broke down because of my running over the dog.*

*My car broke down on account of my running over the dog.*

This is not the case with every sentence, though. Take the following as an example:

*Because of the rain, we now have to stay inside.*

*On account of the rain, we now have to stay inside.*

The phrase "because of" makes the noun "rain" have a more negative connotation versus the phrase "on account of".

Comment: I tried to edit your reply so that the second part said car instead of care, but I needed to change at least six character but there areb't that many characters that need to be changed.

Answer (score -1):

"because of" is the normal expression, "on account of" a less frequent variant.

Comment: This doesn't explain where one should be preferred over another